# Error "Unable to install "project"" after add post_install in xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Try to add new module in a project.
And it shows error about share extension

Fix it with adding post_install in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
    end
  end
end
```

Try to build and succeed, it install correctly in Iphone 10 with IOS 14,2 , But try build it to iphone 12 ios 14,6 . It's build successfully but get error unable to install "projectName"

Error Details:

Details

```
Unable to install "ProjectName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d2f6ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d332550 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001013300d8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d3322a0 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1312
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011d1b5be4 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 2908
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010145a238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010145b824 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 564
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a13d60f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a13d7e90 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a13df678 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a13e0274 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 404
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a13eab44 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a1582ff8 _pthread_wqthread + 276
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a1581d30 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "14.6 (18F72)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 12798;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.5 only supports up to iOS 14.5 (does not support iOS 14.6). See the Release Notes:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5-release-notes

You should install a newer Xcode version.

Comment: Use Xcode 13 get the same error "Unable to install project". And before add the new module it works perfectly with ios 14.5 in xcode 12,5

Comment: After updating Xcode, did you clean & rebuild?

Comment: I've installed 2 xcode version(12,5 & 13,1), because in xcode 13 kingfisher is not work. 

In Xcode 13 i run " command + shifk + k" and click start rebuild but still get the same result